# How to kill a JQuery function while it's running

Tags: jquery

I've written a script that checks to see if the user is active on a page, if not a pop up is displayed after 15 minutes, at which point a timer is displayed which counts down from 60 seconds, and then redirects the user to a page that kills the users session on the website.

However, while I can reset the timer that displays the pop up window, I can't seem to be able to  cancel the second timer that counts down from 60.

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        idleTime = 0;
        idleRedirect = 0;
        // Count for the timer
        var wsCount = 60;

        // Start Countdown
        function startCountdown() {
            if((wsCount - 1) >= 0){
                wsCount = wsCount - 1;
                // Display countdown
                $("#countdown").html('<span id="timecount">' + wsCount + '</span>.');
                timing = setTimeout(startCountdown, 60000);
            }              
            else{
                // Redirect to session kill
                alert('Goodbye');
            }
        }

        // Pop up when the timer hits 15 minutes
        function timerIncrement() {
            idleTime = idleTime + 1;
            if (idleTime > 14) { // 15 minutes
                $('#inactiveWarning').modal('show');
                startCountdown();
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
            var idleInterval = setInterval("timerIncrement()", 5000); // 1 minute

            //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
            $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
                idleTime = 0;
                idleRedirect = 0;
                startCountdown.die();
            });
            $(this).keypress(function (e) {
                idleTime = 0;
                idleRedirect = 0;
                startCountdown.die();
            });
            $(this).scroll(function (e) {
                idleTime = 0;
                idleRedirect = 0;
                startCountdown.die();
            });
        })

    </script>
```

**EDIT** Seems to be some confusion on how I want to cancel the timer. My apologies.

Basically, there is code there that looks for keyboard input, mouse movement, or mouse scroll. When one of these conditions are activated I want the time to be killed with that.

Comment: Tip unrelated to question:  `setInterval("timerIncrement()", 5000);` should be `setInterval(timerIncrement, 5000);`

Comment: And that interval is 5 seconds, not 1 minute

Comment: have you tried to call `clearInterval(idleInterval)` ?

Comment: Honestly, the code / logic doesn't make sense in many places. E.g. startCountdown.die(); doesn't make sense, since startCountdown is not an object. You can't kill a function from an outside while it's running, you can only prevent it from running again using whatever logic/variables you create. See my recommendation below (doTimeout plugin) for what to use to handle timers.

Comment: The code/logic doesn't make sense because I'm developing it. startCountdown.die() was what I thought I could use to kill the function. And I'd sooner learn how this actually works then get involved with a plugin to be honest. I won't learn from using a plugin.

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.7 or higher, because your code can be EXTREMELY simplified if you are.

Answer (score 0):

I always do something like this:

```
    isDead = false;

    function startCountdown() {
        if(isDead) {
            return;
        }
        if((wsCount - 1) >= 0){
            wsCount = wsCount - 1;
            // Display countdown
            $("#countdown").html('<span id="timecount">' + wsCount + '</span>.');
            timing = setTimeout(startCountdown, 1000);
        }              
        else{
            // Redirect to session kill
            alert('Goodbye');
        }
    }
```

now you can "kill" it with setting `isDead` to true.

Also: your code has horrible dumplicity:

```
        function revive() {
            idleTime = 0;
            idleRedirect = 0;
            //startCountdown.die();
            isDead = true;
        }

        $(this).mousemove(revive).keypress(revive).scroll(revive);
```

Comment: i feel like there should be a `while (!isDead)` in there somewhere

Comment: I dont think JS has fully implemented `sleep` method to make `while` solution posiible, maybe in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you check out the doTimeout plugin for jQuery: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/

It would let you do this in 4-5 lines.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your `startCountdown` function:

```
    // Start Countdown
    function startCountdown() {
        if (timing != null) { return; }

        if((wsCount - 1) >= 0){
            wsCount = wsCount - 1;
            // Display countdown
            $("#countdown").html('<span id="timecount">' + wsCount + '</span>.');
            timing = setInterval(startCountdown, 1000);
        }              
        else{
            // Redirect to session kill
            clearInterval(timing);
            timing = null;
            alert('Goodbye');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `clearTimeout()`, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    idleTime = 0;
    idleRedirect = 0;
    // Count for the timer
    var wsCount = 60;
    var timing;

    // Start Countdown
    function startCountdown() {
        if((wsCount - 1) >= 0){
            wsCount = wsCount - 1;
            // Display countdown
            $("#countdown").html('<span id="timecount">' + wsCount + '</span>.');
            timing = setTimeout(startCountdown, 1000);
        }              
        else{
            // Redirect to session kill
            clearTimeout(timing);
            alert('Goodbye');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding it hard to follow what your code is doing, but it looks like you have a massive number of the second timer running, due to multiple calls to `startCountdown()` in `timerIncrement()`.

Try taking advantage of how `setTimeout` and `setInterval` actually work:

```
$(function() {

   var idleTimer = null;
   var logoutCount = null;

   function startLogoutTimer() {
      var wsCount = 60;
      logoutCount = setInterval(function() {
         wsCount--;
         $("#countdown").html('<span id="timecount">' + wsCount + '</span>.');
         if (wsCount == 0) {
            // Perform redirect here
         }
      }, 1000)
   }

   function resetTimers() {
      clearTimeout(idleTimer);
      clearInterval(logoutCount);
      $("#countdown").html('');
      timer1 = setTimeout(startLogoutTimer, 1000 * 60 * 15);
   }

   $(this).mousemove(resetTimers);
   $(this).keypress(resetTimers);
   $(this).scroll(resetTimers);
   resetTimers();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to see how it's done without doTimeout, I would do something like this:

```
var idleTime = 0;
var idleTimeFrequency = 50;
var maxIdleTime = 60000;

function checkIdleTime() {
    idleTime += idleTimeFrequency;

    if (idleTime > maxIdleTime) {
        alert('time up!');
        // note that checkIdleTime() won't be called again 
    } else {
        setTimeout(checkIdleTime, idleTimeFrequency); // check again in 50 milliseconds
    }
}

function resetIdleTime() {
    idleTime = 0;
}

$(document).mousemove(resetIdleTime);
$(document).keypress(resetIdleTime);
$(document).scroll(resetIdleTime);
$(document).click(resetIdleTime);

setTimeout(checkIdleTime, idleTimeFrequency); // call once to get the loop started
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery 1.7 or higher, you can easily shorten this using `.on`, for lesser versions, use `.live`.

Simply use the following and you should have 0 problems. Enjoy!

## Example

```
var idleActivity = 0, idleRedirect = 0, tmrCountDownActivity, tmrCountDownRedirect;
function activity(e) { // e.type will = 'keypress' || 'mousemove' || scroll
    clearInterval(tmrCountDownActivity);
    idleActivity = 0;
    tmrCountDownActivity = setInterval(countDownActivity, 60000);
}
function countDownActivity() {
    if (idleActivity >= 60) {
        //$('#inactiveWarning').modal('show');
        clearInterval(tmrCountDownActivity);
        idleActivity = 0;
        idleRedirect = 0;
        tmrCountDownActivity = setInterval(countDownRedirect, 60000);
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(tmrCountDownRedirect);
        idleActivity++;
    }
}
function countDownRedirect() {
    if (idleRedirect >= 15) {
        clearInterval(tmrCountDownRedirect);
        alert('Goodbye');
        window.location = '/';
    }
    else {
        $("#countdown").html('<span id="timecount">' + (idleRedirect+1) + '</span>.');
        idleRedirect++;
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });

    $(this).on('keypress mousemove scroll', activity);
    tmrCountDownActivity = setInterval(countDownActivity, 60000);

})
```